# Timer Job not getting updated on deployment

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I have a timer job. When I make any changes in it and deploy, it is not taking the updated changes. I referred to many links which told me to change the assembly version and redeploy the timer job,Restart the timer service after deploying the timer job but none of them work for me.

Can any one guide me in resolving this issue. I am stuck in this issue since long. Please guide.

Comment: did you tried an IISRESET?

Comment: More probably reset the timer service (net stop sptimerv4 net start sptimerv4)

Comment: try steps: delete timerjob => restart timer service => add timer job => restart timer service.